# Atualizar meu aplicativo android

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo *android* com um botão de atualização, onde baixo *apk* atualizado e o instalo, mas é necessário fechar o aplicativo, instalar o novo e inicia-lo novamente.

Existe alguma outra forma de atualizar meu aplicativo? Vi em alguns que o aplicativo baixa nele mesmo e já atualiza, sem ter que fechá-lo.

Caso contrário, é possível fazer o meu aplicativo iniciar novamente sem obrigar o usuário a fazer isso?

Comment: Na minha opinião, o mais seguro para os usuários é disponibilizar o app na Play Store e deixar essa gestão de atualizações por lá. Não é uma boa prática forçar o usuário a ligar a opção de instalação de apk's ("fontes desconhecidas") no setup do aparelho só para ele manter o seu aplicativo atualizado, e em contrapartida, deixar uma brecha de segurança aberta.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas é desenvolvimento interno da empresa, não é para usuário externo.